# why does nginx sets root folder to wrong location?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I want to have two servers on my machine, one private, accessible only locally on 127.0.0.1 and one which is visible on LAN (it's root folder is subfolder of the private server). So I have made two configuration files in sites-available and linked them to sites-enabled folder. File `accessible`:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/accessible/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name accessible;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html/accessible/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

and file `localhost`:

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        listen [::1]:80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

After that I have updated /etc/hosts so that http://accessible/ is forwarded to 127.0.0.1: `127.0.0.1       accessible` is the line.

Now when I try to connect to http://localhost/, everything is ok, I get `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` as expected. But when I try to connect to http://accessible/ The same file `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` is displayed. How is that possible? The root folders are apparently set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that localhost server operates on the same IP as I have configured for accessible to be redirected to which is apparently not possible (or at least I don't know how).
I have redirected accessible to 127.0.0.2 (changed line in /etc/hosts to `127.0.0.2       accessible`) which is another address served by local machine and after small change in nginx config file `accessible` that allowed all LAN IP addresses (`allow 192.168.1.0/32;`) everything works just fine (for me on local machine and for computers on network).